# String to BigDecimal

Tags: java, android, database, bigdecimal, searchview

sorry for my english! 
I have a problem with BigDecimal. 
I have created a SQLiteDatabase. Now I want to search with Search View.

```
private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.searchCustomer((query != null ? query.toString() : "@@@@.@@"));

    if (cursor == null) {
        //
    } else {
        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[] { 
                ItemDbAdapter.KEY_1,
                ItemDbAdapter.KEY_2,
                ItemDbAdapter.KEY_3,
                ItemDbAdapter.KEY_4, 
                ItemDbAdapter.KEY_5,
                ItemDbAdapter.KEY_6,
                ItemDbAdapter.KEY_7,
                ItemDbAdapter.KEY_8};

        // Specify the Corresponding layout elements where we want the
        // columns to go
        int[] to = new int[] { 
                R.id.result_1, 
                R.id.result_2, 
                R.id.result_3,
                R.id.result_4, 
                R.id.result_5, 
                R.id.result_6, 
                R.id.result_7, 
                R.id.result_8};

        SimpleCursorAdapter customers = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.customresult, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(customers);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {                
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                np.setValue(100); //Numberpicker


                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);                 


                String 1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("1"));
                String 2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("2"));
                String 3 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("3"));
                String 4 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("4"));
                String 5 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("5"));
                String 6 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("6"));
                String 7 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("7"));
                String 8 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("8"));


                RelativeLayout customerLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.custominfoLayout);
                if (customerLayout == null) {
                    // Inflate the Customer Information View
                    RelativeLayout leftLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rightLayout);
                    View customerInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                            R.layout.custominfo, leftLayout, false);
                    leftLayout.addView(customerInfo);
                }


                Tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_i);
                Tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_a);
                Tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_k);
                Tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_B);
                Tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_k);
                Tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_k2);
                Tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_P);
                Tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_F);


                Tv1.setText(1);
                Tv2.setText(2);
                Tv3.setText(3);
                Tv4.setText(4);
                Tv5.setText(5);
                Tv6.setText(6);
                Tv7.setText(7);
                Tv8.setText(8);

                searchView.setQuery("", true);
```

Until here it works well. What I seek is shown.

If I want to store the values ​​in BigDecimal, I get this error message:

> 10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053): Process: com.XXX.XXXX, PID: 28053
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "0,3"
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:361)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:352)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at java.math.BigDecimal.(BigDecimal.java:344)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at java.math.BigDecimal.(BigDecimal.java:425)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at com.XXX.XXXX.ListeActivity$1.onItemClick(ListeActivity.java:288)
>
> 10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>   10-05 17:58:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(28053):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My proceed as:

```
                Sa = String.valueOf(Tv1.getText());
                Sb = String.valueOf(Tv2.getText());
                Sc = String.valueOf(Tv3.getText());
                Sd = String.valueOf(Tv4.getText());
                Se = String.valueOf(Tv5.getText());
                Sf = String.valueOf(Tv6.getText());
                Sg = String.valueOf(Tv7.getText());




                Big1 = new BigDecimal(Sa);
                Big2 = new BigDecimal(Sb);
                Big3 = new BigDecimal(Sc);
                Big4 = new BigDecimal(Sd);
                Big5 = new BigDecimal(Se);
                Big6 = new BigDecimal(Sf);
                Big7 = new BigDecimal(Sg);
```

I do not understand why this error comes.

I only work with String and BigDecimal, but the error is float.

Comment: Please show your complete stack trace. (I'd also suggest giving your variables more meaningful names, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java [variable names cant be just numbers, or even start with a number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

```
String 1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("1"));
String 2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("2"));
....
```

Later you set

```
Tv1.setText(1);
Tv2.setText(2);
```

the build should have given you warnings.

Comment: Thank you,

i've already written so. 

But if I want to save the value in BigDecimal I get the error message

Comment: please update your question with new changes, get rid of old code

Comment: I have not changed my code. in my code above, I turn to their example.

Comment: In one of your `textView` you have the value "0,3" , this is not a valid number. so BigDecimal fails to create.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the names of the variables `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...` are valid variable names. I recommend to use variable names like `firstColumnText` or an `ArrayList`. So the error you're experiencing might be subject to this.

You also claim that the shown error is `float` but it definitely isn't! `0,3` might be a comma separated list of `BigDecimals` or something else!

From the information you have given I cannot make any suggestion about the problem but issues like that can be avoided by using tools like **checkstyle** with a default android style config.

Comment: Thank you!
the problem was 0,3 

got it changed in 0.3 , now it works